# Trouble Configuring Hbase Interpreter on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: database, configuration, hbase, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I installed both Apache Zeppelin and Hbase via home brew and they both worked on their own. I was able to use Hbase shell in command line and open Zeppelin. I tested Zeppelin with spark and it worked fine.

However, my problem is how do I configure Hbase interpreter? I tried to follow the tutorials given by Zeppelin and it didn't work. [This is the error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tJ2P.png)

I tried to resolve this by resetting the interpreter in the interpreter menu like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g96W.png)  But none of that helped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://stochasticcoder.com/2018/02/12/adding-hbase-interpreter-to-zeppelin-hortonworks/

Comment: I'll look it into it! Thanks!

Comment: @Alan It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. It's considered good behaviour on this site to post the details of your solution as the answer even though it's your own question. Link-only answers are not enough as links can disappear. That way your question and answer will appear in searches and be helpful to others.

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the suggestion. I've posted my solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I meant you should post it as an answer and mark it as answered. That way the question will show up as completed when anyone searches. (And well done for getting it to work!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** 
I was able to resolve the problem by adding the following dependencies to the Hbase interpreter on Apache-zeppelin:

```
/usr/local/hbase-1.2.0/lib/hbase-client-1.2.0.jar
/usr/local/hbase-1.2.0/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.0.jar
/usr/local/hbase-1.2.0/lib/hbase-common-1.2.0.jar
```

**Note:** /usr/local/hbase-1.2.0 is the home directory of Hbase

**Reference:**

- https://stochasticcoder.com/2018/02/12/adding-hbase-interpreter-to-zeppelin-hortonworks/ (Thanks to @Alan)
- For complete guide on installing/configuring hbase interpreter on Apache-zeppelin, you can find it at my repo:  https://github.com/bixingxie/hbase-zeppelin/blob/master/README.md